# element.scrollWidth + absolute magic

Tags: javascript, css

I've found out that if container has absolutely positioned child, it's counted in `scrollWidth`, BUT only if it's on the right or bottom side of parent.
Is it mentioned somewhere in the spec?

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4m6nqq41/5/

Also i've fount that `dir=rtl` changes horizontal behaviour vice versa.

Comment: `scrollWidth` is the total width including when it's overflow. `clientWidth` is the total width without overflows included. Your fiddle has the right returned values. What's the problem?

Comment: This is very unclear, maybe should be closed

Comment: the problem is that they have the very same size, but scrollWidth ignores absolute element on the left, but includes it on the right, it's strange

Comment: It's fine. Overflow in the left doesn't shows scroll. But in the right it shows. It's the normal behaviour, because the scroll is left-to-right.  https://jsfiddle.net/4m6nqq41/8/

Comment: browser seems to be very clever when i do not need it at all) thank you